# Using a dynamic variable to access another variable's value in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

So I'm trying to make my code more modular for sanity purposes (and because it seems more efficient than writing the same code five+ different ways).

However, I'm running against a wall on this one as my JavaScript knowledge is apparently  lacking. 
I've got a method call for buying various unit types. I want to check that the player has enough of a particular type of unit  `citizens` or `soldiers` before training a more advanced type `citizen.workers` or `soldier.specific`. Incrementing the more advanced type isn't a problem I'm addressing yet; I'm simply trying to determine if the base unit is present in a minimum quantity.

What I'm currently using is not working. The type variable is not evaluating but is rather going through as "type" when I want it to default as "citizens". I'm using the variable in 2 places, the if statement for evaluation purposes and in the DB update to reduce the number of that particular field.

Current code:

```
'buy': function(cost, number, type) {
  type = type || "citizens";
  var currentUser = Meteor.user();
  var player = Players.findOne({createdBy: currentUser._id});
  if(player.credits >= cost && cost > 0 && player.type >= number && number > 0) {
    Players.update({createdBy: currentUser._id}, {$inc: {'credits': (0-cost), type: (0-number)}});
    return true;
  }
  return false;
},
```

Searched all over but was not finding what I was looking for or even something I could start with and begin to apply it to what I needed. Any help would be great.

Edit: Yes I realized I was using a default value incorrectly for javascript. I've modified that in my code. The computed value David Weldon answered with was what I was going after more specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in the following ways:

`player[type] >= number`

and

`{$inc: {'credits': (0-cost), [type]: (0-number)}}`

The latter is an example of a [computed property key](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_computed-property-keys-1) which is new in es6.

Also see the 'Variables as Keys' section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes).

Comment: That first line really helped get the if working. However my DB update line still isn't working. It's just decrementing type (which isn't what I'm wanting). I have your line as it was here in your answer and I'm not actually seeing a difference in what I already had. Your help is appreciated though!!

Comment: Thanks so much. I've done a bunch of basic tutorials just hadn't come across these types of things. Appreciate it and now my code is a bit more modular and concise.